# Cloud Vision Api and Photogrammetry

Tags: cordova, image-processing, image-size, google-cloud-vision, photogrammetry

I'm building an android app with `Cordova` in which I want to show two or more photos of objects and resize those photos based on their true length. As a solution, I want to put an object of a known size like a ruler or a pen within the object of the photo so I can find how much to resize the photos. To detect the object of known size I want to use the `Cloud Vision API` and its `Crop Hints` feature. The problem is that the `cloud vision API` only detects the main object of the image. Is there a way I can focus on the other object or should I find another way?

Comment: Cloud Vision Api can now detect multiple objects so its ok

Answer (score 0):

The **Crop hints** requests return the coordinates of a bounding box that surrounds the **dominant object or face** in an image, as mentioned in [the official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/other-features#crop_hints). Based on this, it is not currently possible to define the object in which the service should focus.

In case this feature doesn't cover your current needs, you can use the **Send Feedback** button, located at the lower left and upper right corners of the [service public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/), as well as take a look the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) tool in order to [raise a Vision API feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=0) and notify to Google about this desired functionality.